# Unity3D Touch Rotate Object

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, rotation, touch

I would like to rotate my `gameobject` without using the `z-axis`, so that it only rotates horizontal and vertical.

Right now I am using this code

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        switch(Input.GetTouch(0).phase){
        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            float swipeDistVertical = (new Vector3(0, touch.deltaPosition.y, 0) - new Vector3(0, startPos.y, 0)).magnitude;              
            if (swipeDistVertical > 0)                  
            {                   
                float swipeValue = Mathf.Sign(touch.deltaPosition.y - startPos.y);                   
                if (swipeValue > 0 || swipeValue < 0)//up swipe     
                {
                    vertical = true;
                    horizontal = false;
                }                               
            }               
            float swipeDistHorizontal = (new Vector3(touch.deltaPosition.x,0, 0) - new Vector3(startPos.x, 0, 0)).magnitude;             
            if (swipeDistHorizontal > 0)                    
            {                   
                float swipeValue = Mathf.Sign(touch.deltaPosition.x - startPos.x);                   
                if (swipeValue > 0 || swipeValue < 0)//right swipe
                {
                    horizontal = true;
                    vertical = false;
                }                           
            }

            if(vertical)
            {
                transform.Rotate(touch.deltaPosition.y * 0.3f, 0,0,Space.World);
            }
            if(horizontal)
            {
                transform.Rotate(0,touch.deltaPosition.x * 0.3f,0,Space.World);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I got this code from this [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97540/rotate-gameobject-on-fix-x-and-y-axis-with-touch?newreg=d01d02679ba8462e9fb945752e98b77c)

Right now I can rotate, but it rotates on the z-axis aswell which I don't want. And it doesn't handle the vertical swipe right, it switches between both instead of recognizing that it is vertical right now.

I use Unity 4.6.2 and this should work on `iOS` and `Android`.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code before where you've put "break".

```
float z=transform.rotation.z;
transform.Rotate(0,0,-z);
```